# как передать в event перегрузку методов c# wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, события, делегаты

как передать в event перегрузку методов c# wpf, ситуация - есть button(wpf, mvvm) и есть textBox 5шт, нужно вызвать eventom один из перегруженных методов, сами методы

```
    public void Method1(string a, string b)
    { }
    public void Method1(string a, string b, string c)
    { }
```

Может быть можно организовать "event Action" (может примеры подкидывайте или полезную статью)

Comment: Не совсем понятно в чем ваша проблема. Есть событие. На это событие подписываем метод, который соотв. делегату этого события, далее в этом методе вызываем один из ваших перегруженных методов. Так?

Comment: «нужно вызвать eventom» — а можно расшифровать?

Comment: Так! Только как это реализовать? (В коде) два event делать, и под каждый event свой делегат?

Comment: В подписчике делайте необходимую проверку и вызывайте тот или иной метод. Не понятно в чем проблема.

Comment: Как можно в делегат с двумя принимающими параметрами отправить 3 параметра?

Comment: Сделать делегат с тремя параметрами